# API Python para obter valores real-time de commodities

Tags: python, api

Eu preciso de uma API que possa me fornecer preços em tempo real de commodities (mais especificamente, preço do Café Arábica)

Eu não conheço praticamente nada sobre o mercado de ações, mas pesquisei um pouco e encontrei que os "simbolos" usados para o Café Arábica são alguma coisa como NYCC, KC, KCXXX, onde 'XXX' seriam o mês e o ano do contrato.

Eu tentei usar o yahoo-finance para extrair preços do café mas não funcionou, segue o código abaixo:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
coffe = Share('KC')  # I've tried KC, KCN17, NYCC, KFE.
print(coffe.get_price())
```

O código abaixo foi encontrado na documentação do yahoo_finance e funciona para YHOO, o qual mostra o preço atual da ação do Yahoo.

Também tentei usar o `Quandl` mas não consegui fazer praticamente nada com ele, a documentação dele é bem fraca (pelo menos, se for só aquilo que tem no site, realmente é fraca).

O que eu preciso é uma API que possa me fornecer dados (preços) em tempo real da cotação do Café Arábica (ou qualquer commodity, se funcionar pra uma deve funcionar pra café também).

Pra concluir, não preciso que me digam "esse código aqui faz o que vc precisa", apenas me indiquem a ferramenta que o resto eu dou um jeito.

Answer (score 2):

Embora vc tenha pedido para não postar o código, não encontrei uma forma de explicar apenas textualmente, então resolvi postar, até para saber se realmente funciona, além do fato de que pode ajudar outras pessoas em outros contextos.

Utilzei a API que vc citou "Quandl". No site deles tem os endereços dos datasets, escolhi o "Coffee C Futures, Continuous Contract #1 (KC1) (Front Month)" para fazer o teste, abaixo o codigo. Voce pode vê-lo funcionando em um [notebook no anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/sidon/get_future_coffe/notebook).

```
import requests
import json

url_coffe_futures = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/ICE_KC1'
rjson = requests.get(url_coffe_futures).json()

print (rjson['dataset']['name'])
Coffee C Futures, Continuous Contract #1 (KC1) (Front Month)

print (rjson['dataset']['description'])
Historical Futures Prices: Coffee C Futures, Continuous Contract #1. Non-adjusted price based on spot-month continuous contract calculations. Raw data from ICE.

print (rjson['dataset']['column_names'])
['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Settle', 'Change', 'Wave', 'Volume', 'Prev. Day Open Interest', 'EFP Volume', 'EFS Volume', 'Block Volume']

print (rjson['dataset']['data'][0])
['2017-06-02', 128.0, 128.15, 125.25, 125.55, -2.15, 126.78, 22408.0, 96836.0, 455.0, 52.0, None]
```

[DEMO](https://anaconda.org/sidon/get_future_coffe/notebook)

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta, parabéns.

Comment: Infelizmente a resposta acima não oferece o que eu preciso, acabei de checar para ver se está funcionando (a bolsa está aberta já) mas os preços estão desatualizados, pelo que li sobre esse json ele é atualizado apenas diariamente e isso pra mim não serve, teria que ser uma coisa instantânea, agradeço a resposta e mantive o upvote, porém desmarquei como respondida.

Comment: @gabrielbelini Ai a "culpa" não é do json em si e sim da api (Quandl) o que vc tem que fazer é descobrir uma outra api (provavelmente paga) e aplicar a mesma solução com a nova url.

Comment: Me parece que a própria Quandl, tem uma modalidade de assinaturas (Premium), que talvez atenda o que vc procura. [Pesquise no site deles.] (https://www.quandl.com/)

Comment: Infelizmente a Quandl não oferece esse serviço, mandei email pra eles e me responderam já dizendo que não fazem isso

Comment: Veja o [texto desses caras](http://www.xignite.com/product/XigniteGlobalRealTimeFutures), se não te atender vai ficar dificil. :-)

This API offers real time commodity futures price quotes from major global commodity exchanges such as CME, NYMEX, COMEX, CBOT, Euronext Liffe, Eurex and others. In addition to commodity futures price quotes, the API also provides options, spot prices, and contract termination schedules for contracts written on over 300 underlying assets.